# Rasterio mask removes alpha band

Tags: python, clip, numpy, rasterio, masking

I have a geotiff image that I am clipping to a geojson polygon using `rasterio`.  When I load input the image in QGIS, it has an alpha band (4 bands total).  `rasterio` says it only has 3 bands, which leads me to believe that the `rasterio` sees the alpha band as a dataset mask.  I am using `rasterio.mask.mask` to clip the image to the polygon.  The output of `rasterio.mask.mask` when written to a geotiff is a 3 band image without the alpha band.  Is there a way to include the alpha band/dataset mask in the clipped image?

Here is my code:

```
src = rasterio.open('<input image path>')
output_meta = deepcopy(src.meta)
output_meta["driver"] = "GTiff"

masked_image, masked_image_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, [shape(<geojson geometry>)], all_touched=True, crop=True)

output_meta.update({
    "height": masked_image.shape[1],
    "width": masked_image.shape[2],
    "transform": masked_image_transform
})

with rasterio.open('<clipped image path>', 'w', **output_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(masked_image)
```

Comment: Do you have any other use for the alpha band than to act as a nodata mask? Do you also control partial opacity with alpha?

Comment: @user30184 I am just using it for the NoData mask/transparency in QGIS.  However, my goal is for the clipped image to be as identical as possible to the original image, just limited to the extent of the input geometry.